# error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize' shows up when setting a cv2.resize for frame. What should be done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I was following a tutorial to build facial recognition software:

```
small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.25,fy=0.25),
rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:,:,::-1]
```

when this error showed up:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0)
> /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4052:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'

Comment: The error hints that `frame` is empty. I suggest you check this and if so try to find out what lead to it being empty.

Comment: please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), also [ask] and [mre]. such questions are asked all the time, and have been answered countless times.

Comment: You have skipped the first step recommended in [ask]: "Search, and research". You have also included 2 tags that state in their descriptions "DO NOT USE" in all caps.

Comment: this problem was few times on Stackoverflow. When cv2 can't get frame from file or webcam then it returns `False, None` instead of statis and data  - `ret, frame = cap.read()` - and you should check status `if ret is True:` or check frame `if frame is not None:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was few times on Stackoverflow.

When `cv2` can't get `frame` from file or webcam then it doesn't raise error but it returns status `False`, and frame `None` and you should check one of these values before you run rest of code

```
ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret:  # if ret is True:
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.25,fy=0.25)
    # ... rest of code ...
```

or

```
ret, frame = cap.read()

if frame is not None:  # it can't be `if frame:` 
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.25,fy=0.25)
    # ... rest of code ...
```